# Get RGB from Hue (S & L would be 100)

Tags: colors, rgb, hsl

I need to get the RGB of a HSL with the SL both max. (get RGB from 125, 100, 100)

So, just the hue is changing.

Is there a simple formula for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

See Converting to RGB towards the end of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV

Answer (score 0):

In HSL color mode, if L = 100, then S = 0 and H = undefined.

Comment: He's given H, S, and L, he wants RGB

Comment: You're right, but there is no HSL with those numbers. If L = 100, the only possible numbers are H = undef, S = 0, L = 100 and R = G = B = 255 (white).

Comment: -1. All these answers miss the point of the question. HSL was the wrong term. The guy *clearly* wanted to know how to get a fully saturated RGB color from a hue. He obviously was not asking for white. A reinterpretation taking implied intent would have been way more helpful than obviously giving what amounts to a troll answer (even if its technically correct). The guy was clearly meant to ask about HSV. Explaining why *Lightness* was the wrong term, and and answering the question would have been more helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Yes theres a formula.  RGB = (255, 255, 255).  When L is 100 (max), then your R,G,B is maxed (ie white), no matter what the Hue, or even Saturation.